# How do i get another player's user name and photo, android play games services

Tags: android, google-play-games

```
if (mRoomId != null) {
        for (Participant p : mParticipants) {
            String pid = p.getParticipantId();
            String name = p.getDisplayName();
            if (pid.equals(mMyId))
                continue;
            if (p.getStatus() != Participant.STATUS_JOINED)
                continue;
            int score = mParticipantScore.containsKey(name) ? mParticipantScore.get(name) : 0;
            ((TextView) findViewById(arr[i])).setText(formatScore(score) + " - " +
                    p.getDisplayName());
            ++i;
        }
    }
```

Here is the screenshot...

What I want is user's Name instead of the generated id.

[image]

full code on the link below.

https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/ButtonClicker/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/bc/MainActivity.java

Comment: I think you can use method `getDisplayName()` in `com.google.android.gms.games.Player` class to get the player display name and replace the random name for that. Click out [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Player.html#getDisplayName()).

Comment: i am using exactly that....

Comment: I see ur code that you used `Participant` class not `Player` class and also take look at [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/Participant.html#getDisplayName()). It says `if the identity of the player is unknown, this will be a generic handle to describe the player.` So maybe other player just anonymous

Comment: I have learnt that identity of the other player is kept anonymous...but the thing is even people in my circles are shown as anonymous when connected to the room.